# Splunk eval status codes where the status is multiple

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'd like to eval a status code field where the status is one other the other or multiple.
The blow works for only 200.

```
| eval status = coalesce(status,  $error.status$) 
| where status = 200
```

I'd like to do something like.

```
| where status = 200 OR 201
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

```
| eval status = coalesce(status,  $error.status$) 
| where (status = 200 OR status = 201)
```

Or

```
| eval status = coalesce(status,  $error.status$) 
| where in(status, 200, 201)
```

Or

```
| eval status = coalesce(status,  $error.status$) 
| search status IN(200, 201)
```

Or

```
| eval status = coalesce(status,  $error.status$) 
| search status=200 OR status=201
```